# What varialbes enter the $\min/\max$ in dual problem?

Tags: optimization, linear-programming, duality-theorems

Having the following linear program:

\begin{cases}
\max & -x_1 & -2 x_2&+x_3\\
& -3 x_1 &+x_2 & &\le -1\\
& x_1 &-x_2 & &\ge 1\\
&-2x_1 & +7 x_2 & & \le 6\\
& -5x_1& &+2x_3 &=-3\\
& 7x_1 &-3x_2 &&\le6\\
&x_1\ge0\\
&x_3\le0
\end{cases}

Why do we have:

\begin{cases}
\min &-y_1 &-y_2 &+6y_3 & +6y_4& &-3y_6\\
&-3y_1&-y_2 & -2y_3& +7y_4 & & -5y_6&\ge-1\\
&y_1 &+y_2 &+y_3 &-3y_4&&&=-1\\
&&&&&y_5&+2y_6&=1\\
\forall i\in[[1,5]],y_i\ge0
\end{cases}

And not

\begin{cases}
\min &-y_1 &-y_2 &+6y_3 & -3y_4& &+6y_5\\
&-3y_1&-y_2 & -2y_3& +7y_4 & & -5y_6&\ge-1\\
&y_1 &+y_2 &+y_3 &-3y_4&&&=-1\\
&&&&&y_5&+2y_6&=1\\
\forall i\in[[1,5]],y_i\ge0
\end{cases}

I just read the $b_i$ in the vertical way and put them at the place of the $c_i$ in the dual problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

They changed the order of the  inequalities:

\begin{cases}
\max & -x_1 & -2 x_2&+x_3\\
& -3 x_1 &+x_2 & &\le -1 \color{blue}{\qquad (y_1)}\\
& x_1 &-x_2 & &\ge 1 \color{blue}{ \qquad (y_2)}\\
&-2x_1 & +7 x_2 & & \le 6\qquad \color{blue}{ (y_3)}\\
& 7x_1 &-3x_2 &&\le6\qquad \color{blue}{(y_4)}\\
&  x_3\leq 0 \qquad \qquad  \color{blue}{(y_5)}\\
& -5x_1& &+2x_3 &=-3\qquad \color{blue}{(y_6)}\\
&x_1\geq 0\\
\end{cases}

The second constraint has to be multiplied by 1.

Note that the second constraint of the dual program has to be

$y_1+y_2+7y_3-3y_4+2y_6=\color{red}{-2} \quad (x_2)$

The corresponding coefficient in the objective function is -2 ($-2x_2$).

The others constraints are:

$-3y_1-y_2-2y_3+7y_4-5y_6\geq -1 \quad (x_1)$

$y_5+2y_6=1 \quad (x_3)$